# Error from tabula-java, CalledProcessError

Tags: java, python, pandas, pdf, tabula

I want to convert a PDF file having 2679 pages to pandas dataframe but getting this error. How can I fix it?
Is not the error is due to a large number of pages?

[you can see the error in the picture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6srYb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Dont convert (ALL) pages at once, select a specific page range, 1-3, for example and do it in a loop so you at the end of the loop you convert all pages.

That is java telling you it is running out of memory..

[How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error)